# putAsync and the order of updates on the client

Tags: java, asynchronous, ignite

I didn't find it in the doco, so hope someone can answer.

Say `putAsync` is called multiple times from the same thread:

```
cache.putAsync(keyA, valA1);
cache.putAsync(keyA, valA2); // Notice it's the same key, different value
cache.putAsync(keyB, valB);  // Different key now
// ...more calls with either same or different keys, still from the same thread
```

Is there a guarantee that the values will arrive in the same order to the continuous query listeners set up on the clients?

If not, is there such guarantee in a more restricted case - when those `putAsync`'s above are called from within an Ignite service, for a partitioned cache, on the node where the data is (or will be) stored by the partitioning?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your cache ATOMIC or TRANSACTIONAL? If it's TRANSACTIONAL is it one enclosing transaction? Does keyA and keyB reside in the same partition?

Comment: Thanks @VladimirPligin - it's ATOMIC, and the same partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is guaranteed for the keys within the same partition (see [Data Partitioning](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning)).

There is no guarantee when the keys belong to different partitions.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, that's what I need (sorry for the late reply - I was sure I did!)